# how much is algebra dependent on analysis?

Tags: soft-question, equivalence-relations

Multivariate calculus is dependent on linear algebra. then how much is algebra dependent on analysis? for example, by using the concept of formal derivative, algebra can mimic differential. it seems algebra can develop differential without borrowing any ideas of analysis. is algebra dependent on analysis? because algebra is based on set theory, and set theory is originated from analysis(fourier series)?, how much is algebra dependent on analysis? and there is one more question I want to ask, oneday can algebra mimic everything of analysis?

Comment: In my opinion Algebra is a more basic an foundamental tools.

Comment: how do you get the reals from the rationals without using an analytic construction? Also, I recommend trying to go through the algebraic proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra vs. the 2 line complex analytic one

Comment: Algebra is not dependent on analysis, but certain results of algebra need analytic tools for the proof, e.g., the so-called fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: "oneday can algebra mimic everything of analysis?" One day you will see that there is no sharp separation, but mathematics is highly connected. Many topics of number theory use all kinds of mathematical areas, including analysis (of modular forms), functional analysis, $p$-adic analysis, measure theory, geometry, algebraic geometry, arithmetic geometry, etc.

Comment: To mr.gimusi,mr.qbert,mr.Dietrich Burde. Thank you for teaching new things to me! have a nice day!